# How to programmatically switch between SlideMaster and Default view?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I need to switch in SlideMaster mode with selected main parent slide by button click.
Also I need to return to Default mode and select last selected in this mode slide.

Does anybody know how to do it (for PP2007 / PP2010 / PP2013)?

Thanks

Comment: Will be clear VBA code (not C#) helpful to you?

Comment: Ok. Give me VBA. I'll try to translate into C# if it's feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that in this way in VBA:

```
Sub Switch_To_Slidemaster()

Dim curSLD As Long
    curSLD = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex

'switch to SlideMaster
Application.Windows(1).ViewType = ppViewSlideMaster


'return to default
Application.Windows(1).ViewType = ppViewNormal

'set slide
ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(curSLD).Select

End Sub
```

I hope you cope with converting. 
(Tested for PP 2010)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this code in PP2007, PP2010, PP2013 and it works.

```
private int _slideIndexInDefaultView;

private void ButtonNormalView_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        // Default view
        Globals.AddIn.Application.Windows[1].ViewType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpViewType.ppViewNormal;
        Globals.AddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides[_slideIndexInDefaultView].Select();
    }

    private void ButtonSlideMasterView_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        // Slide master view
        _slideIndexInDefaultView = Globals.AddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex;
        Globals.AddIn.Application.Windows[1].ViewType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpViewType.ppViewSlideMaster;
    }
```